# Show $\sup_x \sqrt{n}|F_n(x) -F(x)|=O_p(1)$ where $F_n$ is the empirical distribution function of a iid RVs with a density function.

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

Let $X_n$ iid RVs with the distribution function $F$ which has a density. Let $F_n(x)= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^nI(X_i \leq x)$ be the empirical distribution function.

Show $$sup_x \sqrt{n}|F_n(x) -F(x)|=O_p(1)$$.

I know by Glivenko-Cantelli thm that $sup_x |F_n(x) -F(x)| \to_{n \to \infty} 0 \  \text{a.s.}$.

I also know that for each $x\in \mathbb R , \ \sqrt{n}|F_n(x) -F(x)| \to _d N(0,F(x)(1-F(x))$ implying  $\sqrt{n}|F_n(x) -F(x)|=O_p(1)$.

I suppose I need to combine those two facts and the fact that $F$ has a density, but I cannot proceed further.

Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Donsker’s Theorem and a functional continuous mapping theorem will do the trick. All you need to show is that the sup map from the functional space to the real line is continuous.

Comment: Wow. Then it turns out I need more machinery to give it a go. Thanks.